# Generating image with regional language

Tags: php, gd

Hi i am trying to generate image with regional language.for normal english i do this

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);
// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';
// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);
// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text); 
// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

But for regional language it won't working...how can i do that

Comment: What do you get if you use non-ASCII text?

Comment: it displays rectangle boxes

Comment: Unable to reproduce that in my PHP 5.3 + IIS 5. Are you sure your PHP file is in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: yes its in utf-8 ..one more thing i am bringing the text from database

Comment: You'll need a version of arial.ttf that supports UTF-8

Comment: Make sure your database is producing UTF-8 strings. One way to check is use `mb_detect_encoding` with properly configured detection order; Lazy way would be output the string to a `charset=utf-8` page and see if it's displaying the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with this piece of code on my machine.

If the strings are coming from the database, is probable that there is a charset problem on it, don't forget to use:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

when connecting to the database.

It should solve your problem.